# How to import amazon s3 for spring boot using gradle kotlin dsl

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have tried to import s3 in my spring boot project following the instructions on the official docs but the dependencies aren't being resolved. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/setup-project-gradle.html

I updated the `software.amazon.awssdk:bom` from the documentation to the latest `2.7.16` hoping this will fix it.

this is my build.gradle.kts file

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.31"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.5.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.7.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.31"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.31"
    kotlin("plugin.noarg") version "1.3.31"
}

allOpen {
    annotation("javax.persistence.Entity")
    annotation("javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass")
    annotation("javax.persistence.Embeddable")
}

noArg {
    annotation("javax.persistence.Entity")
}

group = "com.leaveentry"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.25.0")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.10.5")
    implementation(platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.7.16"))
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:s3")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.10.5")
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.10.5")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

When I try to import s3 related classes, they are not resolved.

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CannedAccessControlList
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar issues and although I didn't manage to make that specific version of amazon bom work, I found a workaround.

Add to your `build.gradle.kts` the following lines:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.228")
    }
}
```

and the following implementation inside the `dependencies` block:

```
implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:s3:2.10.1")
```

Note: Alternatively, you can add the following if you want to include all the services at once:

```
implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:aws-sdk-java:2.10.1")
```